# Converting ISO-8859-1 charcodes to UTF-8

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have an input string that looks like this:

```
4BFC434845000000
```

Every two characters in the input string represent the hexadecimal code in ISO-8859-1.

- The first two characters in the example (`4B`) represent the number 4B<sub>16</sub>, which stands for *K* in ISO-8859-1.
- The second two characters (`FC`) represent the number FC<sub>16</sub>, which stands for the german *u Umlaut* (*ü*) in ISO-8859-1.

The example string above means *Küche*, which is the german word for kitchen.

The input string is guaranteed to be 16 characters long, so the resulting string will always be 8 characters long. Unused characters (like in the example) will be `00`.

I know that I could use [`iconv`](http://php.net/function.iconv) or another function in PHP to convert an ISO-8859-1 string to another character encoding. However I don't know how to convert an ISO-8859-1 charcode (for example FC<sub>16</sub> or 252<sub>10</sub>) to an UTF-8 character.

Of course, I could have an associative array to map all the charcodes to the characters they represent:

```
$table = array(
  0x4B => 'K',
  0xFC => 'ü',
  // ...
);
```

What would the best way to achieve the same? Is there a PHP function that does that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rather trivial: convert the hex string to binary, convert the ISO-8859 binary to UTF-8 binary:

```
$input = '4BFC434845000000';
echo iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', hex2bin($input));
```

Optionally strip out the `NUL` bytes at some point.

Comment: Thanks, `hex2bin` is the solution. But the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) say it's only available in PHP >= 5.4.0. Is there an alternative for earlier versions or would I have to use a polyfill?

Comment: It's seriously worrying if you still need to support PHP < 5.6 at this point; but `pack` is the alternative: `pack("H*" , $hex_string)`.